# If $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree n, then the cardinality of its Galois group is divisible by $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> If $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, then the cardinality of its Galois group is divisible by $n$.

I know I need to use the Tower Theorem, but I can't figure out how to get from there to the solution.

Comment: **Hint:** Construct an extension of the splitting field of degree $n$, by adjoining a root of $f(x)$ to the ground field. Also, as a suggestion, you might want to consider reformulating the question again in the body, not only in the title, for the sake of the convenience of the readers. Regards.

Comment: P.S. I meant *sub-extension*. So please forgive the typo. Thanks.

Comment: It might help to tell us precisely what definition of the Galois group of a (presumably separable) irreducible polynomial $f$ you're using.  If it is just the automorphism group of the Galois closure of $K[x]/(f)/K$, then indeed this seems to follow immediately from the definitions, the Tower Theorem, and the fact that the size of the automorphism group of a finite Galois extension $K/F$ is equal to $[K:F]$.

Comment: You should either say explicitly that $f$ is supposed separable, or mention something about the assumed base field that implies this. Since questions arrive on this site without any context, you **should** mention all relaevant hypotheses; otherwise the question becomes more general than you intended, sometimes much harder, or (as in this case) plainly false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)\in K[x]$ in an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$. Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$. Then $K \subseteq K(\alpha) \subseteq L$, since $L$ contains all the roots of $f(x)$. The size of the Galois group of $f(x)$ is equal to $[L:K]$ (assuming $f(x)$ separable, which is typical.) Now we apply the tower theorem:

$$K \subseteq K(\alpha) \subseteq L \Longrightarrow [L:K] = [L:K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K].$$

Since $f(x)$ is irreducible of degree $n$, it follows that $[K(\alpha):K]=n$. Stringing all this together, we have
$$\#\operatorname{Gal}(L/K) = [L:K] = [L:K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K] = [L:K(\alpha)]n,$$
which is the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution (the one by thyde641 is just fine, of course):

It is easy to show that the Galois group of $f$ acts transitively on the roots of $f$  (here, irreducibility is crucial). We moreover suppose $f$ to be separable, so that it has $n$ distinct roots in its splitting field. A finite group which acts transitively on a set of $n$ elements has order divisible by $n$, by the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Comment: To me this is _the_ proper answer, since it focusses on the essential. It might be good to make more explicit that (1) there are $n$ distinct roots since $f$ is (implicitly presumed) separable, and (2) the product of $X-\alpha$ where $\alpha$ ranges over any Galois-group orbit of roots is a factor of $f$, whence the orbit must contain all roots as $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Dear @MarcvanLeeuwen, you are absolutely right; I have added the condition of separability. Regards,